# String of satellites

Tags: identify-this-object

What appears to be a string of satellites moving nearly overhead towards NW at 10:30pm to 10:50pm Near Eagle River WI on Sun May 26, 2019.

Was lead by 3 equally spaced (approx 1/2 in total length of three at arms length), appro magnitude 4-3.  A couple of min later approx 10 other objects followed in the same line but much dimmer.

Clear night. No Moon.

What was this phenomenon?

Comment: See also [Is the Starlink array really visible from Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36388/12102) It doesn't prove that from your location and time that it was Starlink, but it sounds likely.

Comment: Gizmodo: [Breathtaking View of SpaceX Starlink Satellite ‘Train’ Triggers Wave of UFO Sightings](https://gizmodo.com/breathtaking-view-of-spacex-starlink-satellite-train-1835047155)